# Could not find create work item in App Insight --> End-to-end transaction details

Tags: azure

I have configured App Insight --> work items by referring "https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/application-insights-work-item-integration-with-visual-studio-team-services/"

But, I could not find create a work item in App Insight --> End-to-end transaction details.

I was getting this option a few weeks back. Is there any reason or updates on this?

Could you please explain.

Comment: Hey Syed, unfortunately we had a regression which hid this from the UI unexpectedly. We are working on the hotfix for this right now and will start the deployment ASAP.